# asp.net IIS web deploy, log in error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I'm trying to run an asp.net MVC project deployed from Visual Studio 2013 to IIS. Got it running, but when I log in (app has user authenticatioN) I get:

> *Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.*

Not sure what that means, but based on searching it seems it might be related to this connection string. I have no idea what the problem is though because this string is very different than the ones. This works fine when running from IIS express in visual studio.

```
<add name="ProductDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ProductDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Thanks

Edit: could it be an issue with writing to a folder (inside inetpub on C:/ drive) that has restricted permissions? Or a misuse of LocalDB? Also, when publishing I didn't put anything in the remote connection string textboxes, because I didn't know what to put there. Is that the issue?

If I remove the [Authorize] tag from my HomeController, I get

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.
>       )

These seem to be two separate issues actually. 
I changed setProfileEnvironment to "true" inside my application pool, and that fixed the second issue, but not the first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was missing a connection string for the database that the asp.net identity was using (I copied everything over from a sample project but I didn't know what I was doing so I missed some things)

Here is the line I added inside `connectionStrings`in the project `Web.config` (copied directly from the asp.net sample project I based my own project off of)

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=WebApplication4-2-1-alpha1;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```